# Error Deploy AWS - Ruby on Rails gem ffi updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rubygems

Good morning people,

I'm having trouble deploying on AWS after a ffi gem has been updated, but this gem ffi is used as a dependency on a 5 level gem of the sass-rails.

So I can not set the version I need in this gem that is dependent on the gem sass-rails.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHsft.png)

If someone has already experienced this and can help me? Or know how to arrow a version in a dependency gem.

Thank you very much in advance!

Att, João Henrique Soares

Comment: ¿habla usted Inglés? Because this is an english site.

Comment: Edited question to english. @abybaddi009

Comment: The direct translation from google doesn't help that much. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry for my english, I'm having trouble with deploy in aws as follows in the image. @abybaddi009

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation today with sass-rails when trying to deploy my first AWS project. Keep in mind I am still new to AWS. I don't know that I'd recommend staying on an older version of a gem, but this might help you get running. Here's what I did:

1) Downgrade FFI to 1.9.18. This version seems to install ok on AWS, so I added it to my Gemfile.

```
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'ffi', '1.9.18'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

2) Bundle install to update your Gemlock file

```
$ bundle install
```

3) Commit your changes

```
git commit -am "Updating FFI gem"
```

4) Now hopefully it will install ok. I think you just do but I am coming from a clean app.

```
eb deploy
```

This is what made me think to downgrade the Gem.

https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/613

https://github.com/ffi/ffi/pull/612